# Error in jira plugin development. while running mvn install, even if atlas-mvn clean works fine

Tags: maven, jira, pom.xml, maven-plugin, jira-plugin

[image]

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${amps.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            
            <configuration>
                <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                <!--
                <pluginArtifacts>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                    </pluginArtifact>
                </pluginArtifacts>
                -->
                <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>


                <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                <instructions>
                    <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>

                    <!-- Add package to export here -->
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.atlassian.tutorial.apicall.api,
                    </Export-Package>

                    <!-- Add package import here -->
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                        org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
                        *
                    </Import-Package>

                    <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                    <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Whenever I’m running mvn install I get this error.

Also there’s an error in this line

`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">`

[ERROR] Missing artifact jta:jta:jar:1.0.1Java(0)

If anyone has developed any kind of plugin for jira could you please provide me some codebase to refer?

I've followed so many threads out of which

https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/plugin-com-atlassian-maven-plugins8-0-2-or-one-of-its-dependencies-could-not-be-resolved/30751

it helped me get rid of some of my issues but still errors are not gone completely,